# how to set recursive columns in prisma graphql

Tags: typescript, prisma, typegraphql

so i have a comment model and i wanna add a replies column which is the same type as the comment model. How can i implement it ?

```
model Comment {
  @@map("comments")
  uuid          String      @default(uuid()) @id
  createdAt     DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime    @updatedAt
  body          String      @db.VarChar(255)
  user          User        @relation(fields: [userUuid], references: [uuid])
  userUuid      String
  post          Post        @relation(fields: [postUuid], references: [uuid])
  postUuid      String
  up            Upvote[]
  down          Downvote[]
  upvoteCount   Int         @default(0)
  downvoteCount Int         @default(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As 1 comment can have many nested comments, it would form a 1-many self relation. So something like this should work:

```
model Comment {
  uuid          String    @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt
  body          String
  upvoteCount   Int       @default(0)
  downvoteCount Int       @default(0)
  comments      Comment[] @relation("CommentToComment")

  comment     Comment? @relation("CommentToComment", fields: [commentUuid], references: [uuid])
  commentUuid String?

  @@map("comments")
}
```